# Multivariable Calculus question about the function $f(x,y)=|x|+y^2$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives

I've got this problem in my textbook that I'm a bit unsure about. It is split in two and it reads (translated by me):

i. Explain why the function $f(x,y)=|x|+y^2$ has a greatest and smallest value on the set $D=\{(x,y)\in \rm I\!R ^2:-1\leq x\leq 1, -1\leq y\leq 1\}$.

^I have solved this problem. The next problem is the one that bugs me:

ii. Explain why the smallest value $f$ can have on the set $D$ is found on points where the gradient doesn't exist.

My only guess is that $|x|$ is not differentiable when $x=0$ and thus the gradient cannot exist. Am I on the right track?

Comment: That's _exactly it_ as far as I can tell - not just 'on the right track'! Unless you admit that the partial derivative with respect to x is twice the Dirac delta function of x ... but in the kind of theory you are presenting an instance of here, that's just another way of saying it doesn't exist ... but I _rather like_ the Dirac delta function, & I think it's badly 'done down'!

Comment: Thanks! I dont know anything about the Dirac delta function, though - I'm a 1. semester physics undergraduate student :-)

Comment: Oho! Your tutors will probably say I'm _corrupting_ you - broaching the _sacraments of the __inner temple___ before the proper time! ¶ Actually though, I think you'll encounter it soon enough. Basically it's the function that has a value of ∞ at _one_ single value of its argument, 0 elsewhere, and an integral of 1. In other words, it's a perfect _pulse_. It can be represented as a - limit - $$\lim_{σ\to0}{\exp(-{x^2\over2σ^2})\over\sqrt{2πσ}}$$ is a commonly used one, although _any_ suitably parametrised _central_ function will do. _And_ there are ways of using it _raw_ anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems a bit vague but here's my guess on what it might mean.

You're function $f(x,y)$ is actually differentiable away from the line $x=0$. If it'd have a minimum at $f(x_0,y_0)$ such that $x_0\ne 0$ then we must have $\nabla f(x_0,y_0)=(0,0)$. Can you show why this never happens?